# C2712: Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding

Tags: c++, visual-c++, seh

I am migrating a software writen with VC++ 6.0 to VS 2010/VC++2010. and I have a project which does not compile in Debug mode. I have:

```
LBSC_AppUserInfoList *          
LBSC_Session::GetUsersInfo( const LBSC_Ticket *pTicket )
{
    TSROut_GetUsersInfo sOut;
    C_Buffer            *pcbRet = NULL;
    TSRIn_TicketPar     InPar;
//...
    ClntFree( (void *)sOut.szBuffer );  // dealoca o que veio do RPC

        return( pList );
} // C2712 - Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding
```

and I haven´t any mention to __try

do you undestand?

Comment: Are you sure you don't use any macro that includes a __try? Just try to get the preprocessor output.

Comment: Under your project's properties, go to **C/C++ > Preprocessor** ans set the **Generate Preprocessed File** option.  Then after compiling, look at the output in the .i file with the same base filename as your source file.  See if that contains any usage of `__try`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the most likely problem here is that `ClntFree` is actually a macro that expands out to use an SEH `__try` block.  Nothing else on the surface seems like it would make sense as a macro and a macro seems like the most likely cause here.

Have you looked at the definition of `ClntFree` to see if it's a macro or not?

Comment: That is CIntFree                                                 void
ClntFree( void *pvPointer )
{
 if ( pvPointer ) {
  free( pvPointer );
 }
}

Comment: @michaelhsilva9944 could you post the commented out portion?